# Visual Python - Visualize graphs relating to a movement

Tags: python, graphics

I'm working with visual python on a project where I need to simulate a physical movement.

I'd like to present, in a different window than the one the actual, 3D sim is running, two graphs, both related to the movement:

- How the velocity and angular velocity
  progress over time.
- How the movement and rotation
  progress over time.

All these vars are refreshed once per cycle (inside a `while(true)`)

How can I accomplish this?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've accomplished what I wanted with `gdisplay`. Reference: [here](http://vpython.org/webdoc/visual/graph.html)

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking to do plots of live data you can use matplotlib. Here's a live plotting example:

http://eli.thegreenplace.net/files/prog_code/wx_mpl_dynamic_graph.py.txt  |  [Screenshot](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/wp-content/uploads/2008/08/demo_graph.PNG)

It uses wx but matplotlib has bindings for QT or GTK. Alternatively you could use the [rpy2](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2.html) interface to hook into R which has an excellent plotting engine and may be slightly faster for large amounts of data.

Comment: Link seems broken.